# What is the equivalent of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS / FOUND_ROWS() in N1QL "nickel" Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Is there any built in function in N1QL which is equivalent of  `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` AND `FOUND_ROWS()` in MySQL to use with `LIMIT` , `OFFSET` for prepare Pager purposes?

If no what is the best workaround to achieve same result rather than execute additional N1QL query mentioned below

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mybucket WHERE <same condition that get first result set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the count of full possible resultset in cases where we sort the data (so we can count) and LIMIT the resultset.  sortCount is the total number of possible documents without the limit.

```
select * from `beer-sample` where city > "" order by city limit 10;
...
    "status": "success",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "273.677801ms",
        "executionTime": "273.636223ms",
        "resultCount": 10,
        "resultSize": 8740,
        **"sortCount": 1390**
    }
}
```

Without the ORDER BY, you simply get the following.

```
select * from `beer-sample` where city > ""  limit 10;
...
    "status": "success",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "21.661524ms",
        "executionTime": "21.619021ms",
        "resultCount": 10,
        "resultSize": 10163
    }
}
```

In 4.5, when you have the covering index scan, you can issues a parallel query to do the counting just from the index scan.
The explain will indicate if this "CountScan" method can/is used for the query.

Example:

```
cbq> explain select count(1) from `beer-sample` where city = 'San Francisco';
{
    "requestID": "fe9b3f0f-bfc2-4132-bfd7-6268b78860d4",
    "signature": "json",
    "results": [
        {
            "plan": {
                "#operator": "Sequence",
                "~children": [
                    {
                        **"#operator": "IndexCountScan",**
                        "covers": [
                            "cover ((`beer-sample`.`city`))",
                            "cover ((meta(`beer-sample`).`id`))"
                        ],
                        "index": "idxcity",
                        "index_id": "66d88e11a6178a04",
                        "keyspace": "beer-sample",
                        "namespace": "default",
                        "spans": [
                            {
                                "Range": {
                                    "High": [
                                        "\"San Francisco\""
                                    ],
                                    "Inclusion": 3,
                                    "Low": [
                                        "\"San Francisco\""
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "using": "gsi"
                    },
                    {
                        "#operator": "IndexCountProject",
                        "result_terms": [
                            {
                                "expr": "count(1)"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "text": "select count(1) from `beer-sample` where city = 'San Francisco'"
        }
    ],
    "status": "success",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "4.434551ms",
        "executionTime": "4.382437ms",
        "resultCount": 1,
        "resultSize": 1572
    }
}
cbq>
```

Comment: Thanks @Keshav, but how can we get metrics object within the result if we execute the `n1ql` query through SDK such as php

Comment: Hi @MohammedAl-Hyari - Right now, the only situation you do get this automatically is when the sorting is done. Have this full count is important for pagination.  I've put this in our feature requests: MB-19763.  You can follow that for plans. Thanks.